# Prove that $\sigma:V \to V^*$ such that $\forall v \in V \space\space\sigma(v)=\sigma_v$ is a linear isomorphism

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors

Definition:

We say $T$ is a $k$-tensor if $T$ takes $k$ inputs and is a tensor.

We call $T$ a special tensor if there exists some matrix representation of $T$ which is invertible.

For a vector space $V$, $V^*$ denotes the dual space of $V$.

$L^2(V)$ is the space of all $2$-tensors on $V$.

Question:

Assume that $V$ is a vector space and $T\in L^2(V)$ is a special $2$-tensor. For each vector $v \in V$, $\sigma_v:V \to \mathbb R$ is defined this way:  $\forall u \in V \space\space \sigma_v(u)=T(v,u)$.
Prove that $\sigma:V \to V^*$ such that $\forall v \in V \space\space\sigma(v)=\sigma_v$  is a linear isomorphism.

Note: I proved that its linear and surjective. **But i can't prove its one-to-one.**

Comment: What do you mean by *special*?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I defined it. Does the name matter?

Comment: No, I am apparently just blind.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Actually, i have the question in persian... another word was used instead of "special"... but i didn't know the equivalent in english. So, i called it "special" :)